# Why my CSS does not position my div to the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a div element which contains the language selection links like below:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/page.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="#language">
        <a href="#french">French</a> |
        <a href="#english">English</a>
  </div>
  ...
  ...
</body>
```

I try to CSS the position of #language div to the right side of the page by (*css/page.css*):

```
#language {
    text-decoration: none;

    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}
```

But it does not work, why?

Comment: ps: you want to set the text-decoration on the #language a and not languange... in order to remove the underline from the links

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `#` from `<div id="#language">` and it should work.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/83naR/

Comment: And the reason it works is because the hash mark indicates the name is an 'id' but including the hash in the actual id name makes the hash part of the name, obviously what the OP was not wanting to do.

Comment: Exactly @Rob.  Thanks for adding some explanation.